# Does $X_n \xrightarrow{L_1} X \implies X_n \xrightarrow{\text{qm}} X$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ and $X$ be a sequence of random variables. According to *All of Statistics* (pg. 81), we have that:

$$
X_n \xrightarrow{\text{qm}} X \implies X_n \xrightarrow{L_1} X
$$

But the book doesn't specify whether or not we have the converse:

$$
X_n \xrightarrow{L_1} X \implies X_n \xrightarrow{\text{qm}} X
$$

Is this the case?

**EDIT:** Here, the notation $X_n \xrightarrow{\text{qm}} X$ denotes

$$
E\left[\left(X_n - X\right)^2\right] \rightarrow 0
$$

as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This is the same as saying that "$X_n$ tends towards $X$ in quadratic mean".

Comment: If it was the case, the book most probably would specify that. (Btw what is 'qm'? : )

Comment: @Berci: I clarified the meaning of qm above. Sorry for the initial lack of clarity.

Comment: @user1770201 Convergence in quadratic mean is convergence in $L^2$, that is, $\mathbb E[|X_n-X|^2]\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0$. You wrote $\mathbb E(X_n-X)^2$ which can easily be mistaken for $(\mathbb E[X_n-X])^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence of $X_n$ in $L^1$ does not imply convergence in $L^2$. For a counterexample, let $$\mathbb P\left(X_n = n^{\frac12}\right)= n^{-1} = 1-\mathbb P(X_n=0). $$
Then $$\mathbb E\left[|X_n|\right] = n^{-1}n^{\frac12} = n^{-\frac12}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0, $$ so that $X_n\stackrel{L^1}\longrightarrow 0$, but $$\mathbb E\left[\left|X_n\right|^2\right] = n^{-1}n = 1 $$ for all $n$, so $X_n\not\stackrel{L^2}\longrightarrow 0$.